# Is there any difference running dhcrelay with multiple process or single process?

Tags: linux, configuration, command, dhcp

I want to ask about dhcreay running mechanism. We can run dhcrelay with two command, then it will run as 2 process

```
dhcrelay -i eth3 172.16.17.3
dhcrelay -i eth1 172.16.17.5

#ps ax | grep dhcre
26464 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/dhcrelay -i eth3 172.16.17.3
26465 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/dhcrelay -i eth1 172.16.17.5
```

or with one single command, in other words single process

```
dhcrelay -i eth3 -i eth1 172.16.17.3 172.16.17.5

#ps ax | grep dhcre
28127 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/dhcrelay -i eth1 -i eth3 172.16.17.3 172.16.17.5
```

I wondered if there is any technical difference between these two ways except the process count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking through the [source code](https://github.com/bitrig/bitrig/tree/master/usr.sbin/dhcrelay), there are a couple of things that jump out that would seem to be impacted by running a single command vs. multiple commands.

First this comment in `dispatch.c`:

```
/*
 * Wait for packets to come in using poll().  When a packet comes in,
 * call receive_packet to receive the packet and possibly strip hardware
 * addressing information from it, and then call through the
 * bootp_packet_handler hook to try to do something with it.
 */
```

It would appear that `dhcrelay.c` makes use of a **polling architecture**. This one looks to make use of a timeout (time based) when polling one of the interfaces (for example: **-i eth0** or **-i eth1**).

This would seem to indicate that there is some potential for blocking for one interface while the other is being polled.

Another snippet, this time within the `dispatch()` function, it's polling one of the specified interfaces:

```
/* Wait for a packet or a timeout... XXX */
count = poll(fds, nfds, to_msec);
```

After the poll function above either times out or receives a packet `dhcrelay` moves on to the "next" interface:

```
    /* Get the current time... */
    time(&cur_time);

    i = 0;
    for (l = protocols; l; l = l->next) {
      struct interface_info *ip = l->local;

      if ((fds[i].revents & (POLLIN | POLLHUP))) {
        fds[i].revents = 0;
        if (ip && (l->handler != got_one ||
            !ip->dead))
          (*(l->handler))(l);
        if (interfaces_invalidated)
          break;
      }
      i++;
    }
    interfaces_invalidated = 0;
  } while (1);
```

Notice that the entire `dispatch` contains a `while(1)` loop.

### So what does this all mean?

I would say that if you have a heavily trafficked network with a lot of hosts and your DHCP leases are relatively short, then you **may** want to consider running 2 instances of dchrelay.

If however, your network is relatively small and your DHCP lease timeouts are relatively long, then running a single instance should be fine.

#### Some additional things to consider

- Running 2 instances allows you to maintain separate log files for each.
- Running 2 instances allows one relayer to be restarted without impacting the other.

Comment: I asked this question because I want to send requests from specific interface to specific server. So, according to example in my question, when I run as multiple process, are requests that coming from eth1 relayed to 172.16.17.3 ? or vice versa ?

Comment: BTW I believe you'll need to list both the interface that packets will come in/out from the client, and the interface that packets will come in/out from the DHCP server. Given this your single command may not even be an option.